# is MySQL running on my mac?

Tags: mysql, osx-lion

I have a mac osx lion. I have xampp running (i.e. I click on the icon and then click `mysql` and the red dot becomes green). From there I don't know how to go into the terminal and create a databse. So how do I check that mysql is even installed, from the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can log into mysql with the command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

you will then be prompted for a password; if mysql is not installed you will get an error saying command not found or something similar.

By default, XAMPP will be installed in `/Applications/XAMPP/`, make sure to include the correct path:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql
```

Comment: I get -bash: mysql: command not found. Why would xampp show green if mysql is not there?

Comment: This command will not work, since the XAMPP bin folder is not in the `$PATH`. Try `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql` instead.

Comment: I had the same issue before, for some reason the command wasn't being found in the bin directory; try using the cd command to locate yourself in your bin directory and using the command from there. See notes above.

Comment: So how does this work? @Mathieu Imbert 's answer is correct. So do I accept `Greg`'s answer?

Comment: How do I add `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql` to `$PATH`

Comment: @kasavbere Greg had the right answer, I'll edit it to add the correct path for OS X xampp.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I never got into this situation before.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be to go to your home panel, click on phpmyadmin and try to create a database from there.

As soon as i find a screenshot ill give you one